# How do I implement network call back?

Tags: java, networking

I have crated an interface like this

```
public interface NetworkInterface {

    public void onReceive();
}
```

And I have two classes implementing this interface like this..

```
public class NetworkManager implements NetworkInterface {

    private NetworkQueue    mNetworkQueue;
    private TCPConnection   mTCPConnection;
    private Worker          mWorker;

    public NetworkManager(){
        mNetworkQueue = new NetworkQueue();
        mTCPConnection = new TCPConnection();
        mWorker = new Worker();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


public class TCPConnection implements NetworkInterface{

    private final static String IP = "1.1.1.1"; 
    private final static String PORT = "12001";

    private Socket mSocket; 
    private DataOutputStream mOut;
    private InputStream mIn;

    public TCPConnection() throws NumberFormatException, UnknownHostException, IOException{
        mSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(IP),Integer.valueOf(PORT));
        mOut = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
        mIn = mSocket.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

So TCPConnection is going to import NetworkManager and in the onReceive function of TCPConnection, it will call NetworkManager's onReceive function. In onReceive function of NetworkManager will add anything passing as a parameter to the work queue.

I was wondering if this is the right way to approach the call back function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how TCP networking actually works before you start designing frameworks for it. I suggest you read the Custom Networking trail of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Could you point out what I am missing? I do have some background with networking programming including p2p. I don't see any problem of understanding TCP from my question. My question was about an implementation skill (design pattern)

Comment: @LCYSoft In that case I don't see what your question is actually about.